# Encryption program ascii issues

Tags: c, encryption

I'm working on the same encryption program, for those who saw my earlier post.  Now the program will take letters and it shows the conversion from ascii back to letter, but there's an issue.  Before I added any calulation to the value of the letter it would print fine.  For example, if i put in f, I got 102.  However, when I try a calculation, like multiplying the ascii value by a chosen prime number, the value itself becomes huge!
Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int x,y,z;
int encrypt_number[] = {7507,55529,77933,142867,392263};
printf("\tCaleb's encryption machine\n");
printf("Please enter a letter to be encrypted:\n");
scanf("%[a-z]s",&x);
printf("Enter your encryption key number between one and five\n");
scanf("%d",&y);
if (y == 1)
y = encrypt_number[0];
else if ( y == 2 )
y = encrypt_number[1];
else if ( y == 3 )
y = encrypt_number[2];
else if ( y == 4 )
y = encrypt_number[3];
else if ( y == 5 )
y = encrypt_number[4];
else
printf("not a valid option\n");
z = x*y;
printf("Your encrypted value is: %d\n",z);
printf("\tdiagnosis of encryption:\n");
printf("Letter was: %c\n",x);
printf("value in ascii was: %d\n");
}
```

In the above example, f becomes 264241254!  Hopefully it's a just a simple mistake?

Comment: Why are you looking explicitly for the character `s`?  A scanset conversion specification consists solely of `%[…]`; anything after the `]` is a new item in the format string.  You do not need `s` or `c` after the scanset unless you're really looking for them, and even then, with the preceding `%[a-z]`, the `s` will never be satisfied because it would be eaten by the scanset instead.  Also note that `%[a-z]` accepts a string of 1 or more lower-case alpha characters.  If you want to limit it to one, say so: `"%1[a-z]"`, but you then need to pass a `char array[2];` or longer array.

Comment: You're going to have to worry about reducing the result modulo the size of the alphabet, or something like that. You also need a decryption algorithm.  It isn't immediately clear how you decrypt a number encrypted by your technique.

Answer (score 2):

In `print` line

```
printf("value in ascii was: %d\n");
```

you only give format specifier `%d` but not pass argument which you want `print.`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `%s` to scan (`scanf("%[a-z]s",&x);`) for a single `char` and you are storing the value in `int` variable.

You might want to do

```
char x;
scanf("%[a-z]c",&x);
```

Also, the last `printf` statement has missing argument.

Comment: I appreciate it!  I'm relatively new, and all the feedback is very helpful.

Comment: Why are you looking explicitly for the character `c`?  A scanset conversion specification consists solely of `%[…]`; anything after the `]` is a new item in the format string.  You do not need `s` or `c` after the scanset unless you're really looking for them, and even then, with the preceding `%[a-z]`, the `c` will never be satisfied because it would be eaten by the scanset instead.